# optional /id?/ parameter in React Route path not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning react and I saw a video and the where using a question mark for an optional id parameter passed in the URL path like this

```
<Route path='/cart/:id?' element={< CartScreen />} exact/>
```

the **?** next to **id** is not supposed to be taken as parameter in the URL
The video I saw is from two years and i am using a newer react version I tried to search for the solution but no luck

Comment: RRDv6 removed support for Regular Expressions, so optional parameters are no longer supported. See duplicate for examples utilizing explicit routes. Oddly enough, the code in the duplicate uses an identical path. Possibly code from a code academy project/assignment, or referencing the same tutorial?

Comment: why would they do that, i realised v 4 and 5 is better than 6 but i am already half way throught :(

Comment: I think once you get used to v6 and use it more you might just realize how good an update it is. Sure, some things were dropped, but they got a lot right and fixed a lot of v5's shortcomings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on which version of the react router you're using.

For V1, V2 and V3 optional parameters can be defined as:

```
<Route path='/cart(/:id)' element={< CartScreen />} exact/>
```

For React Router V4,V5 you can use:

```
<Route path='/cart/:id?' element={< CartScreen />} exact/>
```

As for React Router V6, it no longer supports optional routes but instead opts for nested Routes.

```
<Route path="/page/:friendlyName">
  <Route path=":sort" element={<Page />} />
  <Route path="" element={<Page />} />
</Route>
```

[Official docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links) for changes going from V5 to V6. See the relative links section for more information.